# JS не выводит данные в таблицу? Как можно обойти?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Всем привет. Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Есть код типа:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeSum(){
    var sum = $('#33301').val();
    $('#sum').val(sum);
}
</script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type=text name="sum" size="64" id="sum"></td>
    <td id="dd301"><select id="33301" onchange="ChangeSum()" required 
size = “1”>
            <option value="1">Credit History</option>
            <option value="2">DSR</option>
            <option value="3">Income</option>
            <option value="4">Collateral</option>
            <option value="5">FTV</option>
            <option value="6">Geography</option>
            <option value="7">Age</option>
            <option value="8">LOB/LOS</option>
            <option value="9">Other</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
        </select></td>
    <td id="f31"><input></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Не выводит значение в input.
Но если вставляю не в таблицу, а просто поле

```
<input type=text name="sum" size="64" id="sum">
```

, то тут проблем нет.

Как можно вставить данные всё же в таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на JS без дополнительных блоков скриптов.

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td id="sum"> </td>
<td id="dd301">
  <select id="33301" onchange="document.querySelector('#sum').innerHTML=this.value" required>
    <option value="1">Credit History</option>
    <option value="2">DSR</option>
    <option value="3">Income</option>
    <option value="4">Collateral</option>
    <option value="5">FTV</option>
    <option value="6">Geography</option>
    <option value="7">Age</option>
    <option value="8">LOB/LOS</option>
    <option value="9">Other</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td id="f31"><input></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ChangeSum() {
    var sum = $('#33301').val();
    $('#sum').val(sum);
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", ChangeSum);
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sum" id="sum"></td>
    <td id="dd301">
      <select id="33301" onchange="ChangeSum()" required>
        <option value="1">Credit History</option>
        <option value="2">DSR</option>
        <option value="3">Income</option>
        <option value="4">Collateral</option>
        <option value="5">FTV</option>
        <option value="6">Geography</option>
        <option value="7">Age</option>
        <option value="8">LOB/LOS</option>
        <option value="9">Other</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="f31"><input></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="sum" id="sum"></td>
<td id="dd301">
  <select id="33301" onchange="Script.changeHandler($(this))" required>
    <option value="1">Credit History</option>
    <option value="2">DSR</option>
    <option value="3">Income</option>
    <option value="4">Collateral</option>
    <option value="5">FTV</option>
    <option value="6">Geography</option>
    <option value="7">Age</option>
    <option value="8">LOB/LOS</option>
    <option value="9">Other</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td id="f31"><input></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<script>
Script = {
 changeHandler:function(self){
   $('#sum').html(self.val());
 }  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это действительно работает прям как нужно. =)